# The number of rows is not correct with SELECT count in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm, innodb

When I execute query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {TABLE_NAME}` on MYSQL Client, the result is about 100,000 rows.
When the query gets excuted on the appliaction level, however, the result shows only exact 40,000 rows.
It seems like there is some limit while the query is being executed.
Does anybody have any ideas on this?

FYI: I'm using node js and TypeORM for MYSQL with INNODB.

Comment: What investigatory steps have you taken? Have you used your MySQL tracing tools to see **exactly** what the query is? Are you sure the db-name is identical in both cases?

Comment: @Dai I'm debugging the application using vscode and how d I use mysql tracing tool? Db name is the same as it's written in .env file.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-tracing-mysql.html

Comment: @Dai Thank you. I'll check it out. Does this issue have anything to do with data migration by any chance? the data in the tabls has been imported from another db server actually.

Comment: @Dai Plus, TypeORM shows the query log and the query is exactly the same as I put.

Comment: TypeORM cannot tell you the _actual_ queries that MySQL is running - you need to use server-side traces.

Comment: *TypeORM shows the query log and the query is exactly the same as I put.* You need in NOT the query which your client decides to send but the query which MySQL have received actually - only MySQL General Log will provide this info.

Comment: Turn on the "general log" for long enough to capture both `SELECTs`.